# Get-MgDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC not working

Tags: azure, powershell

i used can run this but don't know why it's not working now.
error message:
Get-MgDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC : The term '

```html
Get-MgDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC
```

' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

how may I fix this?

thank you!

my settings:
Get-InstalledModule Microsoft.Graph
Version    Name                                Repository           Description

---

2.3.0      Microsoft.Graph                     PSGallery            Microsoft Graph PowerShell module

Comment: Can you try this command?
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration
Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPc

Comment: Import-Module : The specified module 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: First Install the module Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration and try to import. 
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration

Comment: I am able to install the module and run the commands successfully. check my [output](https://i.imgur.com/ITJc63S.png)

Comment: Is it working for you? Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

> Get-MgDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC not working

I tried the same command to check the `Cloud PC`, but I also encountered the same error.

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `PowerShell` script below to check the `Cloud PCs`

**Power Shell script to check Cloud PC's**

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.DeviceManagement.Administration
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "CloudPC.Read.All"
$Output = "C:\Users\users\Desktop\cloudpc.csv"
$CloudPCs = Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPc -Property "DisplayName"
$DisplayNames = $CloudPCs | Select -ExpandProperty DisplayName
$DisplayNames | Export-Csv -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation
```

**Output**:

[image]

Reference: [Get the default properties of a Cloud PC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/cloudpc-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=powershell)

Comment: there is another problem now:
when I run Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPc without any parameter.

it return 5000 records ONLY, but mine is more than 5000 which is 6***

if I add "-pagesize 6000" , error:

Get-MgbetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC : Invalid page size specified 6000. PageSize must be between 1 and 999 inclusive.

Comment: Page size parameter supports only 1 and 999 not more than. try the below command.
Get-MgbetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC -top 6000

Comment: if above command is not working to fetch 6k records, also try below script.
$filePath = "C:\pathto\file.xlsx"
# Retrieve the first 5000 records and export to Excel
Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC -Top 5000 | Export-Excel -Path $filePath -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow
# Retrieve the next 1000 records and append to the Excel file
Get-MgBetaDeviceManagementVirtualEndpointCloudPC -Top 1000 -Skip 5000 | Export-Excel -Path $filePath -AutoSize -FreezeTopRow -Append